# How to subtract a Sum value from another sum value in SQL Server 2014?

Tags: sql-server, subtraction

I need to subtract a sum of a field which follows condition 'A' from the sum of a field which follows condition 'B'

I've tried different combinations of code to try and get what I'm looking for. But I think the simplest, stupidest code is this one:

```
SELECT A.AccountNumber
      ,SUM(
      (SELECT SUM(FinTransAmt) 
           FROM FinTransMaster
           WHERE FinTransCode IN ('Code01', 'Code02', 'Code03', 'Code04')
       )
    -      -- Minus sign
      (SELECT SUM(FinTransAmt) 
           FROM FinTransMaster
       WHERE FinTransCode IN ('Code05', 'Code06', 'Code07', 'Code08')
       ) 
      ) AS Interest

FROM FinTransMaster ft
   , Account a 

WHERE ft.AcctID=a.AccountId 
  AND a.AccountNumber = '101010101'
  AND CAST (ft.Created as date) >= '2017-06-01'
  AND CAST (ft.Created as date) <= '2017-07-01'

GROUP BY A.AccountNumber
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps another option

```
SELECT A.AccountNumber
      ,Interest = IsNull(SUM( case when FinTransCode IN ('Code01', 'Code02', 'Code03', 'Code04')  then FinTransAmt end),0)
                - IsNull(SUM( case when FinTransCode IN ('Code05', 'Code06', 'Code07', 'Code08')  then FinTransAmt end),0)
FROM FinTransMaster ft
   , Account a 
WHERE ft.AcctID=a.AccountId 
  AND a.AccountNumber = '101010101'
  AND CAST (ft.Created as date) >= '2017-06-01'
  AND CAST (ft.Created as date) <= '2017-07-01'
GROUP BY A.AccountNumber
```

Comment: Thank you, John. This looks neat. Just a quick question, what would be the code to change NULL vales to 0? _____  CASE WHEN ISNULL(FinTransCode, 0) IN ('Code01', 'Code02'.....)  then...

Comment: @user1777929 Sorry, multitasking.  I was going to put the IsNull() and forgot.  See updated answer

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use your query as below by using conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT A.AccountNumber
    ,Sum(case when FinTransCode in ('Code05', 'Code06', 'Code07', 'Code08') then -FinTransAmt else FinTransAmt end) as Interest
FROM FinTransMaster ft
     Join Account a 
     On ft.AcctID=a.AccountId 
  AND a.AccountNumber = '101010101'
  AND CAST (ft.Created as date) >= '2017-06-01'
  AND CAST (ft.Created as date) <= '2017-07-01'
GROUP BY A.AccountNumber
```

Comment: Good use of a logic switch but there may be codes which need to excluded.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Kannan. I appreciate it very much.